# Spring-Boot: a @Component class to hold a List of Database table objects

Tags: java, spring-boot

I need to find a proper solution to have a Spring-Boot @Component (singleton) class hold a List of database table objects, which could be accessed throughout the life of an application. I need to get a value of a certain language column value (there could be many language columns) depending on the parameters.

My idea was to do it like this:

```
@Component
public class CardTypeValueComponent {

    private List<CardTypesTabModel> listOfCardTypes;
    private CardTypesModelRepository cardTypesModelRepository;

    private static final String UNKNOWN = "-";

    @Autowired
    public CardTypeValueComponent(CardTypesModelRepository cardTypesModelRepository) {
        Assert.notNull(cardTypesModelRepository, "CardTypesModelRepository cannot be null");
        this.cardTypesModelRepository = cardTypesModelRepository;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void getAllCardTypesFromDb() {
        this.listOfCardTypes = cardTypesModelRepository.findAll();
    }

    public String getCardTypeLanguageValue(int cardType, String language) {
        String cardTypeLangValue = UNKNOWN;
        for (CardTypesTabModel cardTypesTabModel : listOfCardTypes) {
            if (cardTypesTabModel.getTypeId() == cardType && "spanish".equals(language)) {
                cardTypeLangValue = cardTypesTabModel.getSpanishValue();
            } else {
                cardTypeLangValue = cardTypesTabModel.getEnglishValue();
            }
        }
        return cardTypeLangValue;
    }
}
```

Is it a proper way of completing such a task whilst keeping in mind that the table object column count could increase in the future?

Excuse me for the pseudo code. Thanks.

Added more details:
**CardTypesTabModel** Entity class:

```
@Entity 
public class CardTypesTabModel {
private int type;
private String englishValue;
private String spanishValue;
// other values, getters & setters
}
```

Comment: What do you use to get data from the database? jpa/hibernate/jdbc/spring-data? And do you have an @Entity class?

Comment: @Patrick I use spring-data and `Entity` class is the <CardTypesTabModel> which is 'filled' by using Spring-Data JPA `Repository` interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is re-inventing the caching mechanisme.

You may consider to relay on the Spring Cache Abstraction `http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html` then choose JCache (JSR-107) as implementation.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't fully follow. What is the advantage of using SpringCache over a @Component Singleton which is initialized only once and then returns back data from inside the object upon requests to it?

Comment: It's all about your need and the purpose. I imagine you want to avoid to have access to DB for those "ref" data as it appears they are not supposed to vary a lot during application life, making your own component means you or other developers will have the responsability to maintain it when ever DBs schema changes (one feild changes ==> Entity + Component updates) but if you use the caching you'll naturally invoke your repository and when ever date is there you'll get it instantly with no database round trip.